# Android Development, Google Tutorial

Tags: java, android

I am following the Google tutorial for building your first android application.  I got to the point where I needed to implement the actionbar actions with the functions openSearch() and openSettings().

I implemented all of this in the MainActivity.java file.

My question is this:

In the example app you can type a message and then send it and it displays it in a second activity.  In the second activity, the top action bar changes and does not display my Search icon or perform the action when the settings button is clicked.  In order to have these icons displayed in the action bar for this activity as well, do I need to add those methods and update onOptionsItemSelected method in DisplayMessageActivity.java as well as in MainActivity.java?  Is this the only way to carry the action bar icons/actions over?  To retype the same methods in each activity that you want them in?  Or is there a better way to do it?

My other somewhat related curiosity is this.  The method openSettings() is called when I click the 3 vertical dots and then settings.  These 3 vertical dots show up on every activity, and settings is always in the list.  However clicking settings obviously doesn't perform the call to openSettings() when in the DisplayMessageActivity and not MainActivity.  How is it that settings and the vertical dots are carried over?

Second to last, how can I add other selections to the drop down list from the options/vertical dots in the action bar?  Settings is always there although it responds differently in each activity which was my first question.  But I would like to add certain things to the options menu that are on all activities, and some things that are unique to some activities.  I assume there must be a better way than repeating switch statements and methods in every Activity.java file.

And finally, what is the best practice to implement an action bar over multiple activities?

Obviously different activities will often have different icons/actions in the action bar, however some things like the 3 vertical dots(options) and settings within that would obviously be acceptable to have in every Activity, while it would be nice to add other things to the options list I don't see why settings should ever change across activities. Yet as I stated before the method is not called in DisplayMessageActivity unless I repeat the code in DisplayMessageActivity.java that I had added to MainActivity.java.  I'm confused as to where I can add these so that they are displayed on all activities without repeating code.  And I'm confused as to how the actionbar's options/vertical dots are carried over to all activities while others require the repeating of code in each activities' java file that I want them to show up in.

I know this was a bit of a long winded quesiton, I will clarify if necessary.  I'm just a bit confused.  I was able to make it through the tutorial fine as I have a decent understanding of java.  However google's guide isn't written that well and the Android environment is very confusing to a beginner.

I do understand how things work to a degree, I just want to ensure that I'm actually doing it in a way that when my app grows in complexity it won't be a mess of unnecessarily repeated statements and methods.

Thanks in advance for any assistance and tips.

Comment: I suggest you learn about Fragments. These will provide solutions to all of your questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In order to have these icons displayed in the action bar for this activity as well, do I need to add those methods and update onOptionsItemSelected method in DisplayMessageActivity.java as well as in MainActivity.java? Is this the only way to carry the action bar icons/actions over? To retype the same methods in each activity that you want them in? Or is there a better way to do it?

That is certainly one solution, but as you obviously know, it's not a very good one. There are at least two alternative solutions:

1. Create a `MenuActivity` class which implements all the logic for common menu items and then extend this class from all of your activities, rather than extending the standard `Activity` class.
2. Use fragments to implement your UI. Fragments are similar to activities in that they create UI elements from an XML layout. One difference is that they live inside a "host activity". In this particular case, the host activity will provide the common menu functionality and each fragment can customize it further depending on your needs.

> How is it that settings and the vertical dots are carried over?

Most likely your `DisplayMessageActivity` overrides `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and inflates a menu XML layout which was created by Android Studio (or Eclipse?) when you created the activity class.